# In The Dark Knight, what happened to all the bank robbers?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

The opening scene of *The Dark Knight* shows a bank robbery being perpetrated by a gang hired by the Joker. It transpires that they are all supposed to kill each other, with presumably each of them thinking he will be the only one left to split the takings with the Joker, but as they are all wearing clown masks you only find out towards the end of the scene that

> one of them is The Joker himself.

The scene starts with five robbers; two on the roof, and three in the van.

One is killed by another after he bypasses the emergency phone call. One is killed after he opens the safe.

One is shot by the bank manager after being tricked into believing the manager has run out of ammo in his shotgun, but is shown alive after that as he says to the other "Who taught you how to count?"

One (this same one) is killed

> by the bus when it hits him, and the Joker then kills the bus driver.

We don't see what happened to the other one. Are there any deleted scenes or transcripts that tell us what happened to him?

Comment: You don't need to add the answer into the question, you can either wait for the answerer to update their answer, as you've already commented to them or answer yourself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the record, the [official screenplay](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15824910-the-dark-knight-trilogy) identifies the two men on the roof as **Dopey** and **Happy**, the three men in the car as **Grumpy**, **Chuckles** and **Bozo**.

You've confused Chuckles ([whose gunshot was fatal](https://youtu.be/Joz-tAsJ6as?t=147)) with Grumpy (whose gunshot was '*superficial*')

> **GRUMPY:** *He’s got three left?*
>
> [Bozo raises two fingers. Grumpy squeezes off a shot. The Bank Manager
>   fires. Fires again. Grumpy looks at Bozo, who nods. Grumpy jumps up.
>   The Bank Manager fires. Grumpy grunts as buckshot clips his shoulder.
>   Falls. The Bank Manager moves in for the kill, fumbling for new shells. Bozo
>   stands – shoots him.]
>
> [Bozo picks up the shotgun. Grumpy checks his wound – it’s superficial.
>   He struggles to his feet.]
>
> **GRUMPY:** *Where’d you learn to count?!*

He was killed by the bus coming in through the front of the bank

> **GRUMPY:** *Bus driver? What bus –*
>
> [Bozo steps backwards. Smash. Hostages scream as the tail end of a
>   yellow school bus rockets through the front of the bank, slamming
>   Grumpy into the teller’s window.]

---

For the avoidance of doubt.

- [Happy shoots Dopey on the roof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Joz-tAsJ6as&feature=youtu.be&t=111)
- [Grumpy shoots Happy in the vault](https://youtu.be/Joz-tAsJ6as?t=206)
- [Chuckles is killed by the Bank Manager](https://youtu.be/Joz-tAsJ6as?t=147)
- [Grumpy is killed by the bus](https://youtu.be/Joz-tAsJ6as?t=240)
- [Bozo presumably kills the unnamed bus driver](https://youtu.be/Joz-tAsJ6as?t=240)
- [Bozo survives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eroRVQJLjo)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know they had names. Regardless, one was killed by the bus - possibly the same one that was shot by the manger, I'd have to watch it again, but out of four of them, you only see three killed (roof, safe and bus).

Comment: Ah wait, one was shot in the back by the bank manager.

Comment: Valorum, I have edited the question to make it clear which one's death I was asking about, which was the one shot in the back by the bank manager that I had forgotten about. Do you want to edit your answer to reflect this? Happy to accept it then.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, in the actual film, from what I remember, the convesation goes like this: Grumpy: "He's out right?" & Bozo nods.